# ServiceStack Json DeserializeFromString<Dictionary<string, string>>() vs JsonObject.Parse()

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

They seem to be the same thing at the first look. Because `JsonObject : IDictionary<string, string>`. However, when I try to deserialize the follow sample data, I get different results:

```
 var str1 = "{\"employees\": [" +
            "{ \"firstName\":\"John\" , \"lastName\":\"Doe\" }, " +
            "{ \"firstName\":\"Anna\" , \"lastName\":\"Smith\" }, " +
            "{ \"firstName\":\"Peter\" , \"lastName\":\"Jones\" }" +
            "]}";

//first try
public static JsonObject DeserializeJsonString(this string s) {
    return JsonObject.Parse(s);
}
//second try
public static T DeserializeJson<T>(this string s) where T : class {
    return JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<T>(s);
}
```

First try `JsonObject.Parse()`:

- works fine and parse the object correctly.

Second try `JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Dictionary<string, string>>()`:

- gives me **key value pair of "employees" and "[{"** which seems to be the beginning fragment of the the actual value and the rest of the data chunk is missing.

Why do I have bad data in the 2nd way?

EDIT -------------------------------------------------------

NO LONGER AN ISSUE.

Latest version of SS has patched this problem. Now it can parse Dictionary`<string, string>` just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Source code in ServiceStack.Text -> DeserializeDictionary.cs 
//Line 89
//if type is JsonObject : Dictionary<string, string>
    var mapKey = keyValue;
    var mapValue = elementValue;
//Line 145
//if type is Dictionary<string, string>
    var mapKey = Serializer.UnescapeString(keyValue);
    var mapValue = Serializer.UnescapeString(elementValue);
```

That's why:

```
var a = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Dictionary<string, string>>():
//returns <"key", "[{"> incorrect value
var b = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<JsonObject>();
//returns <"key","[{...}]"> correct value
```

JsonObject is inherited from `Dictionary<string, string>`, but it is assigned a different meaning than a normal `Dictionary<string, string>`to have special treatment. To me 'a' and 'b' should return the same answer, either both works, or both don't work. Now 'a' is broken and 'b' works, I personally think this is a logical error.

Comment: It's parsed differently by design, `Dictionary<string,string>` is expecting JSON string values which get un-escaped, whilst `JsonObject` assumes that you want to dynamically parse JSON so it doesn't attempt to un-escape the raw value as a JSON string - letting you further dynamically parse the JSON object graph.

Answer (score 1):

I would ask myself why the second call is allowed at all.

For `Dictionary<string, string>` I would expect a JSON string to look like `{ "key1": "val1", ...}` but it is `{ "key1": not a string, ...}` instead. I would expect it to fail (or return null) because of invalid or unexpected JSON format.

Comment: Hmm, your answer didn't cover it... JsonObject is Dictionary<string, string>, right? and JsonObject.Parse(string json) { return JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<JsonObject>(json);} from SS source code, right? why does that work?

Comment: @Tom Sorry, I missed that you're using the ServiceStack implementation. Usually a JsonObject implements something like IDictionary<string, JsonValue>. I think they got reasons for their decision (maybe my answer reflects that... maybe). That's something you should ask the actual developers.

Comment: np thanks for trying :) I found out the reason, thinking how to deal with it. Please see my answer above

Comment: I see that you're getting different results there, but I think that decision for this was made on purpose. JsonObject != string Dictionary (it's just misleading that JsonObject extends that dictionary). I could try to explain my assumption in my answer why they decided so (and why I agree) but I think the actual developers know better...

Comment: my libraries were 6+ months old, I "update all" nuget and it fixed the problem, now 'a' and 'b' both works

Comment: Great, I'm glad you could fix your problem (and contribute to everyone which might ask himself the same thing) ;-)